# Create nested dictionary in a for loops

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to create nested dictionary which is supposed to look like:

```
{'4/1': {'A': 5, 'B': 6},  '4/2': {'A': 1, , 'B': 7}, '4/3': {'A': 4, 'B': 3}}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
{'4/1': {'A': 5}, '4/2': {'A': 1}, '4/3': {'A': 4}}
```

Code:

```
import random
import datetime as dt

futuresIncome = {}
incomeTypes = ["A", "B"]

for incomeType in incomeTypes:
    for month in range(4, 5):
        for day in range(1, 4):
            date = str(month) + "/" + str(day)
            
            if date in futuresIncome.keys():
                continue
            else:
                futuresIncome[date] = {}
                futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: In your outer loop, you add a key for each date for `"A"`, then on the next iteration (`B`) you then check if the key is there (which it is) and then `continue`, so your second iteration doesn't do anything. Try use `pdb` to debug this, you'll see that you always hit the `continue` path once you get to the B iteration.

Comment: also, instead of `futuresIncome[date] = {}`, consider using a `defaultdict(dict)` instead. And you can change `date = str(month) + "/" + str(day)` to `date = f"{month}/{day}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `defaultdict`:

```
import random
import datetime as dt
from collections import defaultdict

futuresIncome = defaultdict(dict)
incomeTypes = ["A", "B"]

for incomeType in incomeTypes:
    for month in range(4, 5):
        for day in range(1, 4):
            date = str(month) + "/" + str(day)
            futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not `continue` in the `if` block but add the data for the current `date`:

```
if date in futuresIncome.keys():
    futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)
```

You could also make use of the [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method and get rid of the `if-else` block:

```
for incomeType in incomeTypes:
    for month in range(4, 5):
        for day in range(1, 4):
            date = str(month) + "/" + str(day)
            futuresIncome.setdefault(date, {}).update({incomeType: random.randint(1, 11)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if date in futuresIncome.keys():
                continue
```

This part causes that

```
            else:
                futuresIncome[date] = {}
                futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)
```

will be executed only once if futuresIncome doesn't contain this date.

Probably you wanted to do something like that:

```
            if date in futuresIncome.keys():
                futuresIncome[date] = {}
            futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)
```

Generally, better option than that would be [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest iterating through incomeTypes in the innermost loop as shown below:
`

```
import random

import datetime as dt

futuresIncome = {}

incomeTypes = ["A", "B"]


for month in range(4, 5):

    for day in range(1, 4):

         for incomeType in incomeTypes:
            date = str(month) + "/" + str(day)
            
            if date in futuresIncome.keys():
                continue
            else:
                futuresIncome[date] = {}
                futuresIncome[date][incomeType] = random.randint(1, 11)`
```